# How do I remove Chainlink on Linux

Tags: chainlink, ubuntu

If I want to remove an installation and start fresh which directories and files should I rm? This is on a system with a remote database and chain  (I'll delete the node database manually with psql if that doesn't present issues?). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Docker, stop your node by clicking `CTRL + C` & remove the container and its volumes by typing `docker rm -v chainlink`.

After that, remove the Docker image by typing `docker image ls` to see all Docker images on your system and then find `IMAGE_ID` for `smartcontract/chainlink` and type `docker image rm IMAGE_ID`

Finally, delete the `~/.chainlink` directory and its contents.

If you are running node from source, delete the directory containing the source code cloned from the repo.

Comment: Thanks - the ~/.chainlink directory had escaped me!

Comment: On reflection this is an answer for docker and does not answer the question? eg the gobin directory still has the chainlink executable and a great deal of other stuff, and these arent removed by this solution. I think this is an answer for docker but the question is about linux as per the title thnx.

Comment: Thanks again btw for answering - I'm having some success by deleting the ~./chainlink dir plus the gobin dir contents. I don't delete the source I just make install from it again - which is much quicker so there is still stuff in place I guess?